# soundcloud api gives blank page

Tags: php, curl, soundcloud

when i try soundcloud api (http://api.soundcloud.com/users/mezomefans.json?consumer_key=xxxxxxxxxx) it gives data

```
{"id":153870451,"kind":"user","permalink":"mezomefans","username":"mezomefans","last_modified":"2017/05/15 18:45:01 +0000","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/153870451","permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/mezomefans","avatar_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000280458917-j6ilmo-large.jpg","country":null,"first_name":"","last_name":"","full_name":"","description":null,"city":"","discogs_name":null,"myspace_name":null,"website":null,"website_title":null,"track_count":1,"playlist_count":0,"online":false,"plan":"Free","public_favorites_count":28,"followers_count":9,"followings_count":12,"subscriptions":[],"reposts_count":0}
```

but when i try to php it gives me blank page and not give any data

My code is :

```
<?php
$url = file_get_contents("http://api.soundcloud.com/users/mezomefans.json?consumer_key=xxxxxxxxxx");
preg_match("'\"followers_count\":(.*?),'si", $url, $matches);
$followers = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $matches[1]);
echo $followers;
 ?>
```

Any Idea how to retrieve data via php?

Comment: the above does not show any `curl` code. TBH I'd be surprised if the api endpoint was not `https`

Comment: Any idea how to retrieve data in php and not show as blank page ?

Comment: never looked at their api until now - you have, I presume, read their API documentation fully? https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#authentication

Answer (score 0):

That's the old `users` endpoint, you should be using the `/users/{USER_ID}` endpoint.

First, get the user ID of the user (153870451).

Then, construct your request:

```
HTTP GET: http://api.soundcloud.com/users/153870451?client_id={CLIENT_ID}
```

Response:

```
{
  "id": 153870451,
  "kind": "user",
  "permalink": "mezomefans",
  "username": "mezomefans",
  "last_modified": "2017/05/15 18:45:01 +0000",
  "uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/users/153870451",
  "permalink_url": "http://soundcloud.com/mezomefans",
  "avatar_url": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000280458917-j6ilmo-large.jpg",
  "country": null,
  "first_name": "",
  "last_name": "",
  "full_name": "",
  "description": null,
  "city": "",
  "discogs_name": null,
  "myspace_name": null,
  "website": null,
  "website_title": null,
  "track_count": 1,
  "playlist_count": 0,
  "online": false,
  "plan": "Free",
  "public_favorites_count": 28,
  "followers_count": 9,
  "followings_count": 12,
  "subscriptions": [],
  "reposts_count": 0
}
```